# jQuery slideshow not appearing in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, slideshow

I have been trying to edit this slideshow for ages now and for some reason it wont appear in either IE's Quirks mode or IE7 standards mode.

The slideshow is here - http://www.justdesignit.se/webshop/general/startpage/delaval/start_delaval2.html

The same slideshow is being used here - http://www.justdesignit.se/webshop/general/startpage/cp/start_cp2.html which works in IE7 & Quirks mode

Any help would be great, I'm tearing my hair hour here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible error :

`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.justdesignit.se/img/loading.gif`

Add this file and you'll be ok..

Comment: I removed the reference to that image (The client doesn't need it) and it still wont work in IE7

Comment: just see at the bottom if you get any yellow '!' double click that and tell the error from that.. I mean IE status bar

Answer (score 1):

it was the DOCTYPE.....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 //EN">
```

use this ...